# Pushing Elements to a JSON Array with Braces

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am having a hard time trying to `push` elements to a JSON file located in an external location; here's a backstory on what I am trying to achieve:

I am programming a private Discord bot and am currently working on the message-system portion of it. The whole idea is that a user's message is deleted if they aren't fully authorized onto the server; that user's **message and UserID** will be logged into the JSON file . The thing is, I can **only log** the message if a UserID is manually added to the array (using the `push` function, I can add the message). But, if I try to `push` a UserID to the file array, it acts as if the `push` function does not exist for this; I think the JSON  is *nested* as well. I would appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

**JSON**

```
{"users":[{}]}
```

*I want to put the UserID within the braces inside the brackets*

**Code to `push` to the JSON**

```
function removeMessage(content, authorid) {
    if (!messagedata.users[0][authorid]) {
        messagedata.users[0].push(authorid);
    }
}
```

**Current I'm Getting:**

> TypeError: messagedata.users[0].push is not a function

**Expected Output**

```
{"users":[{"287423028147781654":["Hi"]}]}
```

*The numerical value is the UserID, while 'Hi' is clearly the message*

Comment: I'm very confused about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to `push` to a file?

Comment: show a clear, expected output

Comment: To change the JSON, you have to parse it into an object, modify the object, and then stringify it back to JSON (provided you want to keep the medium as JSON).

Comment: I have added an **expected output** and changed my terminology about the JSON.

Comment: What is the actual output?

Comment: The **actual output** when trying to ``push`` is --> ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined``. My code sees the external JSON file, but has a hard time trying to push to **only** ``messagedata.users[0]``

Comment: look into the `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` methods

Comment: I reran the code and now I am getting ``TypeError: messagedata.users[0].push is not a function``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`users[0]` is an object, not an array (and hence has no `push` method). It appears you actually want to add a key to the object, so try this instead:

```
messagedata.users[0][authorid] = ["Hi"];
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was looking for! Thank you!